# Не подключается jQuery к сайту

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь подключить jQuery к html сайту.
Подключаю google CDN

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script scr="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Создала js файл app.js. В нем

```
$(function() {
    var header = $("#header"),
    introH = $("#intro").innerHeiqht(),
    scrollOffset = 0;

    $(window).on("scroll", function(){

        scrollOffset = $(this).scrollTop();

        if( scrollOffset >= introH ){
            header.addClass("fixed");
            }else{
                header.removeClass("fixed");
            }
    });
    });
```

И когда перехожу на сайт, нажимаю f12, консоль не выдает никаких данных. Что не так, почему не получается подключить js файл?

Comment: "консоль не выдает никаких данных" - какие данные Вы ожидаете увидеть в консоли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте путь прописать ./assets . Также внутри вашей функции напишете console.log('1'), чтобы проверить подключился ли файл

Comment: к сожалению, не работает:(

Comment: $(function() { console.log('1')
    });  Попробуйте так написать, также проверить есть ли файл по этому пути

Comment: нашла у себя ошибку. писала scr вместо src) но все равно спасибо больше за помощь)

Comment: Ничего, можете закрыть вопрос, чтобы другие не заходили

Comment: ух, теперь он ругается, что Uncaught TypeError: $(...).innerHeiqht is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: Он выдаёт ошибку, т.к. у вас нет элемента с этим id